# Add .c files in a package using Autotools without compiling them

Tags: build, automake

I have some .c files that get included in some unit tests (like *#include "foo.c"*). I don't want the build system to try to build those. It will fail. I just want to call 'make dist' and get those .c files included in the generated package.

How do I do that? I've tried **noinst_** prefix and **_DATA** suffix without effect.

Also, a link to the specific documentation would be great. I'm running in circles reading GNU's documentation on this. It's huge (as it should be)!

Comment: It must be pointed out that `#include "foo.c"` is a bad idea.  `*.c` files should be compiled, `*.h` files should be included.  Never include a `*.c` file!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
EXTRA_DIST = foo.c
```

Comment: Works. Also, it could be dist_foo_DATA. Don't know why I thought it didn't work before. I just have to define some foodir guy :)

Comment: @haole: That will install `foo.c` into `$(foodir)`, which is fine if that's what you want.